# "first private company"

Tags: articles, headlinese

> SpaceX becomes first private company to launch humans into orbit. [Source](https://amp.ft.com/content/e3deff5d-4c55-4e6b-a3e8-e6b5fa6ff162?__twitter_impression=true)

Is it correct to use "the first" or "a first" here？What's the difference among them if so?

Comment: In a title (newspaper style), they often leave out the **the** which would not be **left out** in writing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["No smoking allowed" or "No smoking is allowed"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/85020/no-smoking-allowed-or-no-smoking-is-allowed)

Comment: Although the specific grammar is different, it's still essentially the same question as the one referenced in the previous comment. In *headlinese*, various parts of grammar are omitted.

Answer (score 1):

> "SpaceX becomes first private company to launch humans into orbit"

Sounds like a media headline. And headlines often shorten language that way. The whole sentence sounds very unnatural in any other context.

Comment: I'll learn more about these. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

"The first" because there is only one "first" being referred to.

You could write, "SpaceX launched humans into orbit, a first for the company," but that would be specifically limiting it to SpaceX -- it would still be true if a dozen private companies had launched humans into orbit already.